# How to make JpaRepository without types, or to make jpa repo with only queries?

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-repositories

I have a couple repositories to work with entities (add,update, delete etc.). And I want to use JpaRepository to fetch statistic data only with @Queries methods, with no update, delete and other CRUD methods. Is there in spring JPA some solution for this case? If I use JpaRepository<PaymentList,Long> I bind to he PaymentList type and get CRUD methods, but to add or delete entities I have distinct repo, and if I use JpaRepository without types I get exception. One of the solutions is to owerride methods from JpaRepository and throw exception while using them, but it looks a bit ugly.
Here is the example of my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StatisticRepo extends JpaRepository<PaymentList,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT pd.date, SUM(pd.totalPayment) " +
            "FROM PaymentDetails pd WHERE pd.date BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_until " +
            "GROUP BY pd.date")
    List getDailyExpensesStatistic(@Param("date_from") Date dateFrom,
                                   @Param("date_until") Date dateUntil);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I found is to use org.springframework.data.repository.Repository. No matter with what type of entity or id. It don't have any methods to store or get data. Maybe someone has better solution...